Troubleshooting a Quasi-Periodic Function Fit in Python: Why Isn't My Curve Matching the Expected Formula?
I'm trying to fit a quasi-periodic function with a trend term to my time series data using Python. The data has been generated by following a series of steps. First, an interval of dates spanning from January 2011 to December 2020 was created, with monthly frequency. These dates were then converted into a numerical format where each date is represented as a combination of its year and month. The formula for the date convertion is as follows:
$$\text{date_numeric} = \text{Year} + \frac{\text{Month}}{12} $$
For example, if the date is "June 2015," the numeric value would be:
$$\text{date_numeric} = 2015 + \frac{6}{12} = 2015.5 $$
This value allows for continuous representation of time, where each month contributes a fractional part of the year to the overall numeric value.
Using this numerical representation, a specific formula was applied to compute the corresponding values. The formula incorporates trigonometric functions and constants to generate the values.
Specifically, the values for the curve were calculated using the formula $y = 2 + 3x - 6 \cos(2x) + 5 \cos(\pi x)$. In this formula $x$ represents the numerical format of each date (i.e., a continuous variable derived from the date)
Finally, a dataframe was constructed containing both the dates and the computed values. This dataframe was then saved to an Excel file for further use or analysis.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Loading the Excel file
file_path = r"C:\Users\xx\quasi-periodic\data_long_generated.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(file_path)


# Extracting the two time series
observation_date = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
HSN1FNSA = df['value']


# Converting dates to numbers (necessary for the fitting function)
x_data = (observation_date - observation_date.min()).dt.days.values
y_data = HSN1FNSA.values

# print(df.to_dict())

def quasi_periodic_func(x, *params):
    n = (len(params) - 2) // 3
    a = params[:n]
    lambdas = params[n:2*n]
    phases = params[2*n:3*n]
    constant = params[3*n]
    trend = params[3*n + 1]
    result = constant + trend * x
    for i in range(n):
        result += a[i] * np.cos(lambdas[i] * x + phases[i])
    return result

# Number of components to use in the quasi-periodic function
n = 3  # Replace 3 with any desired number of components

# Initial guess for the parameters
# The initial guess needs to have 3 * n elements: n amplitudes, n frequencies, and n phases
initial_guess = [0] * n + [2] * n + [0] * n + [50, 0.1]

# Fitting the quasi-periodic function to the data
params_opt, params_covariance = curve_fit(
    quasi_periodic_func, x_data, y_data, p0=initial_guess,maxfev=2900000
)

# Print the optimized parameters
print("Optimized parameters:")
for i in range(n):
    print(f"a_{i} = {params_opt[i]}")
    print(f"lambda_{i} = {params_opt[n + i]}")
    print(f"phi_{i} = {params_opt[2*n + i]}")

# Create the fitted data
y_fit = quasi_periodic_func(x_data, *params_opt)

# Plot the results
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(observation_date, y_data,label='Observed data', color='blue')
plt.plot(observation_date, y_fit, label='Quasi-periodic fit', color='red')
plt.xlabel('Observation date')
plt.ylabel('HSN1FNSA')
plt.title('Quasi-Periodic Fit of HSN1FNSA Data')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

However, when I run this code, the fitted curve is completely off. And here's what the fitted curve looks like:

Why I didn't obtain $y = 2 + 3x - 6 \cos(2x) + 5 \cos(\pi x)$ as the fitting curve?
Any suggestions on how to improve the fit would be greatly appreciated!
